# Elasticsearch Multifields Indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Suppose I have a field named 'Title' and I want to index it using different analyzers (standard and english). Is there a difference between using a Multifield Mapping, or creating two separate fields?

With multifield mapping:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-fields.html

```
"mappings": {
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "title": { 
                "type":     "string",
                "analyzer": "english",
                "fields": {
                    "std":   { 
                        "type":     "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With two separate fields:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "title_standard": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "title_english": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "english"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is how you will send the fields to elasticsearch.

With a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/multi-fields.html) you will need to send only one field and elasticsearch will create a new field using the analyzer or type specified in your mappings.

Using two fields you will need to make a copy of the original field before and send both of them, they are treated as two different fields for elasticsearch.